# Comparing two columns in a dataframes in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two columns that are similar to each other in two data frames

I want to compare these columns and return those values which do not match with each other
example:

```
df_1["detail"]= ["X25", "i20", "Sunny120", "A22" ]
df_2["temp_detail"]= ["i20", "A22", "sunnY120", "X 25"]
```

Expected output:

```
X25 
Sunny120
```

These values are not same there is a spacing error and a case error

Can anyone kindly please help me with this code in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [left_anti](https://sparkbyexamples.com/scala/spark-sql-left-anti-join-with-example/) join for that.

```
df_1.join(df_2, df_1.detail === df_2.temp_detail, "left_anti").select("detail").show()

df_2.join(df_1, df_1.detail === df_2.temp_detail, "left_anti").select("temp_detail").show()
```

Comment: Accepting the answer would be appreciated :)